# AWS API Gateway Enable Cloudwatch Logs via Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am writing deployment scripts in Python using boto3 for an API Gateway.  The script will create the API, resources, methods, and deployment.  When I look in the AWS Management Console there is a checkbox for `Enable CloudWatch Logs`

[image: CLoudWatch Logs Option]

Is there a way to enable this via boto3 or the REST API?  I haven't seen any options in the documentation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available in update_stage in boto3 (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.update_stage)

The patch paths are documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/stage-update/

You can use a patch operation like below to set log level on all resources/methods

```
   { "patchOperations" : [
    {
        "op" : "replace",
        "path" : "/*/*/logging/loglevel",
        "value" : "INFO"
    },
   }
```

Comment: As noted above, the `patchOperations` is an array, so multiple values can be set in a single endpoint call.

Answer (score 1):

The cloudwatch log setting you are looking for is associated with a stage resource. In your case, you need to use the [`update_stage`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.update_stage) method in boto3 to apply a patch operation to set the correct log level.

From the boto docs:

> **loggingLevel** (string) --
>
> Specifies the logging level for this method, which effects the log
>   entries pushed to Amazon CloudWatch Logs. The PATCH path for this
>   setting is /{method_setting_key}/logging/loglevel , and the available
>   levels are OFF , ERROR , and INFO .

Here is the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/stage-update/) to the update stage REST API reference.